# how to remove # from href value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I need to remove '#' from href value, I had used  replace method but its not working. Suppose I get value in `targetId=#general1`,from that I need to remove `#` and i need to append it to another class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {    
        var targetId = $(this).attr('href');    
        $('#activepage').text(targetId);
    });
})
```

Comment: `replace` should work for you , As you said it's not working,Can you please post the `replace function` code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3y4x8cw1/1/ try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply replace

```
$('#activepage').text(targetId);
```

with

```
targetId = targetId.charAt(0) === "#" ?  targetId.substring(1): targetId;
$('#activepage').text(targetId);
```

Comment: `targetId` may or may not have `#`..Just to avoid any side effects..And _I'm not the DOWNVOTER_

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6u3wd413/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("href").replace("#",""));

    });

});
```

This will work fine though it will replace all `#`

Comment: O really? What if I use `##something`, or `a##b`? :) [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6u3wd413/2/)

Comment: I already stated that it will replace all `#`. If you want to remove first `#`, @gurvinder answer is best